# Monodroid - Camera Activity isn't returning

Tags: android, mono, camera

I'm trying to take a picture in one of the activities of my application using the Camera, save it and return the file location for further usages.
However, when I press the ok button in the camera activity, nothing happens (Cancel work though).

I'm using an emulator.

There is the code used to call the Camera Activity:

```
FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.exSetPicture).Click += delegate { 
            var dir = new Java.IO.File (
                Android.OS.Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory (
                Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryPictures), "MySuperbPictures");


            if (!dir.Exists ()) {
                dir.Mkdirs ();
            }

            _file = new Java.IO.File (dir, String.Format ("Picture\t{0}.jpg", Guid.NewGuid ()));
            Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(Android.Provider.MediaStore.ActionImageCapture);  
            cameraIntent.PutExtra (MediaStore.ExtraOutput, Android.Net.Uri.FromFile (_file));
            StartActivityForResult(cameraIntent, SET_NEW_PICTURE); 
        };
```

Solutions I found that seemed not to work for me:

- Checking App permissions (Camera, external storage are set)
- Making sure folder is created (Breakpoint did show it wouldn't go in the if (!dir.Exists())
- Setting the IntentExtra as a new File instead of directly Uri.FromFile(folder)

I'm kinda stuck for now.. It's probably something really stupid but I can't get why it's not working..

Help would be apreciated :P

**Edit:**

This is the part of my "OnActivityResult" related to that:

```
        protected override void OnActivityResult (int requestCode, Result resultCode, Android.Content.Intent data)
    {
        int ResultID = 0;
        base.OnActivityResult (requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (data != null) {
            if(resultCode == Result.Ok) {
                switch (requestCode) {
                case SET_NEW_PICTURE:
                    var contentUri = Android.Net.Uri.FromFile (_file);
                    PhotoLocation = contentUri.ToString();
                    FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.exViewPhoto).Visibility = Android.Views.ViewStates.Visible;
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: make sure u are overriding `onActivityResult` to get result back from camera Activity ?

Comment: Hey, I did, then I might have done it wrong :P
I added the code to the first post. (Removed the part regarding to others activities return)

Comment: It doesn't when I click ok, yet it does when I press cancel...
I really don't get it. (I've set a breakpoint in OnActivityResult to check)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved: seems that Android didn't like the "\t" in the file name...
Somehow.. And this is part of the Monodroid documentation fml.